# Why is Gunicorn file not visible in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn, fastapi

I have an application using Gunicorn as my http server and I'm creating a docker container. However, after I try `docker run`, it gives me this stackstrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 414, in run
    do_run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2500, in do_run
    run_fn(*run_args, **run_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2447, in do_run_posix
    os.execve(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/api/.venv/bin/gunicorn'
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9

# environment variables
ENV API_DIR /api

# installing pipenv library
RUN pip install pipenv

# setting the working directory
WORKDIR ${API_DIR}

# copying pipenv normal and hashed dependencies onto container 
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ${API_DIR}/

# copying rest of application onto container
COPY ./ ${API_DIR}/

# installing dependencies directly to python distribution package on deploy mode 
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy

# --deploy version
CMD ["pipenv", "run", "gunicorn", "main:app", "--access-logfile", "-", "--worker-tmp-dir", "/dev/shm", "--workers", "4", "--threads", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080"]

# --dev version
# CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "main.py"]
```

Telling Gunicorn to use `dev/shm` instead of `/tmp` still doesn't work. What could be a solution?

Comment: Run a shell and inspect what's in there.

Comment: Since you're using `--system` there isn't a `venv` for that installation; are you sure you need `pipvenv run` and can't invoke `gunicorn` directly?

Comment: @MatsLindh Oh wow I didn't even think of that. I was able to get it working.